# SproutCore Confusing in Binding ListView Content to ArrayController

Tags: sproutcore

In SproutCore, it is a common way to bind the ListView.content to an ArrayController:

```
Todos.todosController = SC.ArrayController.create({
});

SC.ListView.design({
    contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Todos.todosController'),
    exampleView: SC.CheckboxView.design({
      ..........
    })
})
```

But the "content" field of ListView which extends from SC.CollectionView is SC.Array, should't it be:

```
contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Todos.todosController.content')
```

Any explanation will be appreciated. Sorry for the poor english.

@TopherFangio I looked at the implementation of `SC.ArrayController` and find out that `.arrangedObjects` is a very simple computed property that returns the object it belongs to:

```
arrangedObjects: function() {
    return this;
}.property().cacheable()
```

So binding to `.arrangeObjects` is actually the same as binding to: `App.arrayController.arrangeObjects`

I also find out `SC.ArrayController` extends `SC.Array` and implements the two required methods 'replace()' and 'objectAt()'.

> To support SC.Array in your own class, you must override two primitives to use it: replace() and objectAt().

The implementation of these two methods in `SC.ArrayController` will do some array controller specific check and forward the request to the `.content` property.

So just like @TopherFangio said, `SC.ArrayController` is a proxy for it's underlying `.content` property. If i bind to `App.arrayController.content` directly rather than the controller itself, i think i will lose all the arrayController goodness.

Thanks again for your great help @TopherFangio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SC.ArrayController](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.ArrayController&src=false) is actually a proxy object which does some nice things for you.

You can certainly bind to the `.content` property, but you could also bind to the `.arrangedObjects` property and set the `orderBy` property. This would let you modify `orderBy` and have the bound list automatically update. In general, this is what you want to do.

Additionally, I believe that `Todos.todosController.length` will always be a number, even if the content is null. In contrast, calling `Todos.todosController.content.length` would throw an error if `content` was null.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. It turns out that i didn't read the document carefully. So actually bind to the Todos.todosController is the same as bind to Todos.todosController.arrangedObjects ?

Comment: @merlin I actually have no idea; it is either the same as binding to the `.arrangedObjects`, or binding to the `.content`. For some reason, I'm thinking that it's the `.content`, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Yes binding to `Todos.todosController.arrangedObjects` is the same as binding to `Todos.todosController`, as `arrangedObjects` just returns `this`. But getting in the habit of binding to `arrangedObjects` lets you overwrite the `arrangedObjects` property in the odd occasions that you need to. It also makes it very clear as to your intentions. Binding to `content` of a controller would defeat the purpose of using the controller as it would completely bypass it.

Comment: @geoffreyd Ahh, I was curious about that! Thanks for the clarification :-D